# what is the unversioned models in sagemaker?

Tags: machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I read the sagemaker model registry [doc](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.create_model_package). It mentioned versioned models and unversioned models. But the doc lacks a clear description of how these two behave differently for model management/deployment.

Here is the definition in the doc

> There are two types of model packages:
>
> Versioned - a model that is part of a model group in the model registry.
> Unversioned - a model package that is not part of a model group.

Answer (score 0):

Unversioned Model Packages are those that are available for use in AWS Marketplace. You can use AWS Marketplace to share model packages you have created.

When using the Model Registry to track and manage your models, they are represented as Model Package Versions within Model Package Groups. These "versioned" Model Packages are "not" available for use in AWS Marketplace.

I work for AWS & my opinions are my own